# error in creating an incident in servicenow

Tags: servicenow

I am trying to create an incident in servicenow using the http post method. I am using the HTTP post method by sending across incident creation data using JSON.
as follows:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://myInstance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident");
    String postData = "   {\n" +
                    "      \"upon_approval\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"location\": {\n" +
                    "        \"link\": \"https:\\/\\/dev13413.service-now.com\\/api\\/now\\/table\\/cmn_location\\/1083361cc611227501b682158cabf646\",\n" +
                    "        \"value\": \"1083361cc611227501b682158cabf646\"\n" +
                    "      },\n" +
                    "      \"expected_start\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"reopen_count\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"close_notes\": \"Closed before close notes were made mandatory\",\n" +
                    "      \"impact\": \"1\",\n" +
                    "      \"urgency\": \"1\",\n" +
                    "      \"correlation_id\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"sys_tags\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"sys_domain\": {\n" +
                    "        \"link\": \"https:\\/\\/dev13413.service-now.com\\/api\\/now\\/table\\/sys_user_group\\/global\",\n" +
                    "        \"value\": \"global\"\n" +
                    "      },\n" +
                    "      \"description\": \"User can't access email on mail.company.com.\",\n" +
                    "      \"group_list\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"priority\": \"1\",\n" +
                    "      \"delivery_plan\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"sys_mod_count\": \"21\",\n" +
                    "      \"work_notes_list\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"follow_up\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"closed_at\": \"2015-10-29 23:10:06\",\n" +
                    "      \"sla_due\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"delivery_task\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"sys_updated_on\": \"2016-01-28 20:16:07\",\n" +
                    "      \"parent\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"work_end\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"number\": \"INC0009871\",\n" +
                    "      \"closed_by\": {\n" +
                    "        \"link\": \"https:\\/\\/dev13413.service-now.com\\/api\\/now\\/table\\/sys_user\\/9ee1b13dc6112271007f9d0efdb69cd0\",\n" +
                    "        \"value\": \"9ee1b13dc6112271007f9d0efdb69cd0\"\n" +
                    "      },\n" +
                    "      \"work_start\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"calendar_stc\": \"7937181\",\n" +
                    "      \"business_duration\": \"1970-01-22 21:46:21\",\n" +
                    "      \"category\": \"network\",\n" +
                    "      \"incident_state\": \"7\",\n" +
                    "      \"activity_due\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"correlation_display\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"company\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"active\": \"false\",\n" +
                    "      \"due_date\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"assignment_group\": {\n" +
                    "        \"link\": \"https:\\/\\/dev13413.service-now.com\\/api\\/now\\/table\\/sys_user_group\\/d625dccec0a8016700a222a0f7900d06\",\n" +
                    "        \"value\": \"d625dccec0a8016700a222a0f7900d06\"\n" +
                    "      },\n" +
                    "      \"caller_id\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"knowledge\": \"false\",\n" +
                    "      \"made_sla\": \"false\",\n" +
                    "      \"comments_and_work_notes\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"parent_incident\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"state\": \"7\",\n" +
                    "      \"user_input\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"sys_created_on\": \"2014-05-29 18:24:13\",\n" +
                    "      \"approval_set\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"reassignment_count\": \"1\",\n" +
                    "      \"rfc\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"child_incidents\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"opened_at\": \"2015-10-28 23:09:51\",\n" +
                    "      \"short_description\": \"Can't read email\",\n" +
                    "      \"order\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"sys_updated_by\": \"admin\",\n" +
                    "      \"resolved_by\": {\n" +
                    "      \"link\": \"https:\\/\\/dev13413.service-now.com\\/api\\/now\\/table\\/sys_user\\/6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441\",\n" +
                    "      \"value\": \"6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441\"\n" +
                    "      },\n" +
                    "      \"notify\": \"1\",\n" +
                    "      \"upon_reject\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"approval_history\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"problem_id\": {\n" +
                    "      \"link\": \"https:\\/\\/dev13413.service-now.com\\/api\\/now\\/table\\/problem\\/9d3a266ac6112287004e37fb2ceb0133\",\n" +
                    "      \"value\": \"9d3a266ac6112287004e37fb2ceb0133\"\n" +
                    "      },\n" +
                    "      \"work_notes\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"calendar_duration\": \"1970-04-02 20:46:21\",\n" +
                    "      \"close_code\": \"Closed\\/Resolved by Caller\",\n" +
                    "      \"sys_id\": \"9c573169c611228700193229fff72400\",\n" +
                    "      \"approval\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"caused_by\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"severity\": \"1\",\n" +
                    "      \"sys_created_by\": \"pat\",\n" +
                    "      \"resolved_at\": \"2016-01-28 19:56:12\",\n" +
                    "      \"assigned_to\": {\n" +
                    "        \"link\": \"https:\\/\\/dev13413.service-now.com\\/api\\/now\\/table\\/sys_user\\/46b87022a9fe198101a78787e40d7547\",\n" +
                    "        \"value\": \"46b87022a9fe198101a78787e40d7547\"\n" +
                    "      },\n" +
                    "      \"business_stc\": \"1892781\",\n" +
                    "      \"sys_domain_path\": \"\\/\",\n" +
                    "      \"cmdb_ci\": {\n" +
                    "        \"link\": \"https:\\/\\/dev13413.service-now.com\\/api\\/now\\/table\\/cmdb_ci\\/b0c4030ac0a800090152e7a4564ca36c\",\n" +
                    "        \"value\": \"b0c4030ac0a800090152e7a4564ca36c\"\n" +
                    "      },\n" +
                    "      \"opened_by\": {\n" +
                    "        \"link\": \"https:\\/\\/dev13413.service-now.com\\/api\\/now\\/table\\/sys_user\\/681ccaf9c0a8016400b98a06818d57c7\",\n" +
                    "        \"value\": \"681ccaf9c0a8016400b98a06818d57c7\"\n" +
                    "      },\n" +
                    "      \"subcategory\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"sys_class_name\": \"incident\",\n" +
                    "      \"watch_list\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"time_worked\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"contact_type\": \"\",\n" +
                    "      \"escalation\": \"0\",\n" +
                    "      \"comments\": \"\"\n" +
                    "    }";
```

I get an error response output as follows:
I am not sure what are the required fields in the create incident.
    HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
    {"error":{"message":"Operation Failed","detail":"Error during insert of incident (INC0009871)"},"status":"failure"}

Answer (score 1):

A 403 error means you're not passing credentials to the endpoint. It looks like you're missing an Authentication header

Try the following after Line 1:

```
String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode ("<%your username%>:<%your password%>");
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```